# Replace existing object in array with new value

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I have multiple dropdown menu, I am trying to update the value of an object if it exists in the array

my onChange is as follows

```
          onChange={e => {
            const answer = {
              id: questionChoice.id,
              name: questionChoice.text,
              value: e,
            }
            let newAnswer = {
              ...currentAnswer,
            }

            if (!currentAnswer.value) {
              newAnswer.value = [] // init empty array
            }

            if (index in newAnswer.value) {
              console.log('found')
              console.log('here', index in newAnswer.value)
              newAnswer.value = newAnswer.value.filter(item => item.value !== answer.value)
            }

            newAnswer.value = [...newAnswer.value, { [questionChoice.text]: answer.value }]
            console.log('new answer', newAnswer)

            updateCurrent(newAnswer)
          }}
          optionFilterProp="children"
          onFocus={onFocus}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          filterOption={(input, option) =>
            option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
          }
        >
```

my current output is this

```
newAnswer.value: [
0: {Inform producers about the range of sustainability practices: "1"}
1: {Inform producers about environmental management: "7"}
2: {Provide mentoring services to new advisors: "12"}
3: {Inform producers about the range of sustainability practices: "2"}
]
```

expected output would be

```
newAnswer.value: [
0: {Inform producers about the range of sustainability practices: "2"}
1: {Inform producers about environmental management: "7"}
2: {Provide mentoring services to new advisors: "12"}
]
```

Right now it's appending any new result from `newAnswer.value = [...newAnswer.value, { [questionChoice.text]: answer.value }]`

However I am finding the correct object with

```
if (index in newAnswer.value) {
                  console.log('found')
                  // replace object here
                  newAnswer.value = newAnswer.value.filter(item => item.value !== answer.value)
               }
```

Just not sure how to change specific objects in place

Comment: Your outputs are not of any valid known format

Comment: it's an array of objects?

Comment: What is `index`, where does it come from, and why are you using the `in` operator?

Comment: At the very least: `if (index in newAnswer.value) { ` is wrong, because `index` is global. You need to declare index as a local first, usually by putting `let` in front of it.

Comment: However, you're not actually using `index` anyway, so this is suspicious at least.

Comment: @invrt I would suggest that you store your answers in a different format than an array of single-keyed objects, which is really horrible to work with. Change it to either a single object of many entries (question-answer mapping), or to an array of tuples (object with two values, a question and an answer).

Comment: I have updated my post to show the full component, where `index` is being used

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#find` to find the object and update the property value after.

```js
const value = [{
  'Inform producers about the range of sustainability practices': "1"
}, {
  'Inform producers about environmental management': "7"
}, {
  'Provide mentoring services to new advisors': "12"
}];
let questionChoice = 'Inform producers about the range of sustainability practices';
let newAnswer = '2';
let obj = value.find(o => o.hasOwnProperty(questionChoice));
if(obj != null) obj[questionChoice] = newAnswer;
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out,

changed

`newAnswer.value = [...newAnswer.value, { [questionChoice.text]: answer.value }]`

to
`newAnswer.value[index] = { [questionChoice.text]: answer.value }`